# How to filter the output in powershell for class

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

How to filter this output in PowerShell with Enddate in below output

```
$expiryApps = $appRegistrations | Where-Object { $_.PasswordCredentials.EndDate -lt $thresholdDate } | Select-Object DisplayName, objectID, PasswordCredentials
 foreach($i in $expiryApps){
     $ExpieredKey = Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -objectID $i.objectID 
     foreach($expiry in $ExpieredKey){
         write-host $expiry
     }
 }
```

i get this output and i need to filter by Enddate here

```
class PasswordCredential {
  CustomKeyIdentifier: 
  EndDate: 9/9/2023 6:30:00 PM
  KeyId: 
  StartDate: 9/8/2023 6:30:00 PM
  Value: 
}

class PasswordCredential {
  CustomKeyIdentifier: 
  EndDate: 3/6/2024 9:02:26 AM
  KeyId: 
  StartDate: 9/8/2023 9:02:26 AM
  Value: 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to filter this output in PowerShell with Enddate in below output

I have created some applications with secret `end dates` set to `'2023-12-07'` for the purpose of fetching the secrets.

**Application**

[image]

Here is the updated script to filter the application secrets with end date.

```
    $thresholdDate = Get-Date "2023-12-07"
    $appRegistrations = Get-AzureADApplication
    
    foreach ($app in $appRegistrations) {
        $PasswordCredentials = Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
        foreach ($credential in $PasswordCredentials) {
            $formattedEndDate = $credential.EndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
            if ($formattedEndDate -eq $thresholdDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) {
                Write-Host "Application: $($app.DisplayName)"
                Write-Host "  PasswordCredential:"
                Write-Host "    EndDate: $($credential.EndDate)"
            }
        }
    }
```

The script will check all applications, and if the end date matches, it will display the application.

**Output:**

[image]